# What "things" does the OS have to save for each process?

Tags: process, operating-system

There is a question from an old Operating Systems exam where I really don't know the answer to.
The Question is: "What "things" does the OS have to save for each process? (Name at least 5)"

So far I have:

- Address space
- Process-ID
- Processor registers (like PC,...)
- Childs
- Open Files

But I am not sure if these things are correct.
Do you know any better points?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above is right. OS also keep information about process state(running or waiting), CPU scheduling information, userId, group ID, device allocated, signals etc..